# How slide a control like in iOS in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have a control inside a form. This show another control on top of it when a event happend, then it disappear and show the first control.

I wish to have a smooth "slide-in/out" animation like is common in iOS, instead of appear/disappear.

I see that firemonkey have some animation components, but have no clue in how use them.

Comment: what about http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsfmxtableview.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the TFMXObject.AnimateXXX functions: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject_Functions (TFMXObject is a parent of all FireMonkey controls, so you can use these functions for any control).

A few samples using AnimateFloat:

```
Panel1.AnimateFloat('Left', -Panel1.Width);
ListBox1.AnimatFloat('Height', 0, 0.5, TAnimationType.atOut, TInterpolationType.itBounce);
Edit1.AnimatFloat('Opacity', 0, 1);
```

AnimateFloat animates any floating point property. First parameter is the property name (as a string), second the ending value, next the time period (in seconds), which direction to animate (atIn, AtOut), and finally the algorithm to use - see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TInterpolationType for all the options.

You also got: 
AnimateColor (animate a color property);
AnimateFloatDelay (start an animation after a given delay);
AnimateFloatWait (wait until the animation finished - useful for chaining animations).

plus, StartAnimation and StopAnimation for use with animations in a style.

Comment: Just for passers-by with newer Delphi versions: TFmxObject.Animators are deprecated and you should use the FMX.Ani.TAnimator.Animation methods instead. To do so simply add FMX.Ani to uses clause and call `TAnimator.AnimateFloatWait(Edit1, 'Opacity, 0, 1);` to implement the last line in above solution.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely!

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Image_Effects

Despite the name, these effects apply to controls too, not just bitmaps.
Also check out the sample projects supplied (shadereffects)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the animation functions.

I've built something like this, animating TPanel. I start with the Position.X property off screen and animate the panel into view with something like this, where Self is the form:

```
Panel1.Align := TAlignLayout.alNone;
Panel1.Position.X := Self.Width + 10;
Panel1.Position.Y := 0;
Panel1.Width := Self.Width;
Panel1.Height := Self.Height;
Panel1.AnimateFloatWait('Position.X', 0, 0.3);
```

In the form's OnResize event:

```
Panel1.Align := TAlignLayout.alClient;
```